# Is there a way to link a question to more than one stack exchange site?

Tags: feature-request, migration, serverfault

I posted the following question, and answer (for documentation purposes), to Stack Overflow since that is where I originally looked for the answer (and didn't find one):

[Installing Web Deploy on IIS 7+ with Shared Configuration enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632763/installing-web-deploy-on-iis-7-with-shared-configuration-enabled)

I thought it might fit on Server Fault as well so I was going to copy the question and answer over but was unsure if that was appropriate or if there was a better way of going about it.  Just like copying and pasting code is not a good programming practice, is there some way to reuse this question/answer on Server Fault?

Comment: No, you can not link it to more than one site. If you think it is more suitable for another site, then you can flag it and ask a moderator for migrating it to Server Fault.

Comment: @FallenAngel I don't think it is 'more' suitable but might be useful there as well.  Like I said we originally found bits and pieces of info on Stack Overflow to help move forward.  Server Fault though is somewhere people might look for this information as well and that is why I thought it might be useful to be found there as well as Stack Overflow.